# Resize an already drawn rectangle paperjs

Tags: vue.js, paperjs

I am creating a rectangle in a canvas using paper JS. The following is code for drawing the rectangle in vue.js.

```
created () {
    const toolDrag = event => {
      let trackingRect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(event.downPoint, event.point)
      trackingRect.strokeColor = new paper.Color('#2661D8')
      trackingRect.strokeColor.alpha = 0.7
      trackingRect.strokeWidth = this.strokeWidth

      trackingRect.removeOn({
        drag: true,
        up: true
      })
    }

    // Finalise rectangle properties and draw.
      let $this = this;
    const toolUp = event => {
      let newRect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(event.downPoint, event.point)
      newRect.strokeColor = new paper.Color(this.getColor().stroke)
      newRect.fillColor = new paper.Color(this.getColor().fill)
      newRect.strokeWidth = this.strokeWidth
        newRect.selected = true;

      // Custom data attribute:
      newRect.data.type = 'rectangle'
      newRect.data.class = ''
      // Flag the annotation has been edited and the changes are not saved
      this.flagAnnotationEdits()
    }

    this.toolRect = new paper.Tool();
    this.toolRect.onMouseDrag = toolDrag;
    this.toolRect.onMouseUp = toolUp;

  },
```

Now I want to allow user to resize this drawn rectangle by dragging any corner of the rectangle, but I am kind of stuck and unable to understand how to do this.

I have seen solutions for resizing a rectangle by changing bounds, but could not find solution for my use case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve what you want.
One of the simplest that I found is to recreate the rectangle, each time you drag one of its corners.
This way, you only have to know the dragged corner position and the opposite corner position and you can easily create the proper rectangle.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/fVZta+NGEP4rU0OJTXy6Unpf7LoQmrR3cHcNccMVckdZSytra2lXrNZW0+D/3pl9kVaKEkMg2pd5npl5ZmafZpJVfLaabQ/cpMVsOUtVRt9v38KfhWig4cYIuW8gVdJoVTZgCg4Fk1nJcVf8x5Ov+qvE3cbA+6vP1x9vtn/fXV1/uN/CBt6taZP+gr28ZHtgZalaOKItBQeJ/7YFl9ByYJpDptl+j5DApMexCCU3/dYGclY2fB1bbkVZQmMUmiCKKs+RO+RaVRFlqFUjjFCSoHHZG6jUsUFk1Uo8IKRJnEnHk8EOg8C1hYf7vzo6DuI1EtYYaF5r3nBJgXTcakuD405qmNwjr1RpiRBE19uzByVHcLpmXedZj+1N3BJCHOUvHPGZNrB7hFRzZkFZhCSkNV2JjOKhcvuVMnliTRK70t+wTu2IbV2ylGfAWVqAERUmLBDHC2OKvYGNY8Lvwsr8JHibpBgSvPoG3v2whHjlElcWQ+lwuSSBODu9NCBX2tEJjlg6kScY+M4BTHJGia9UJvJHe74n2RSsjsUcNL7pzyQN31dIsUkqVs/n/muJIc34vwvY/AKSt3DLTJH0rj6RScAf5XYF/lLipPFmVDPLcNio8dHLl47m6N2vqlR6BRdKIyi/6PaCIIIgvUnHGHbqKDNXCVTqNU9FLtIQWi+U9IjXq8hgxgwDtfsHPUwi1Y+Leumquk8VHkxLkR54FtNrC4HZ63jZRpNyTGJGCiYC/ERBCFcIfQVP4cYHcmTl/TnHhv+QcVmriEmSdNaU/ERnrvHICvKjTKk3zC3iArrMeYt4b4+6Rhtxnwm1HFxwDWR09YsXIfERBkpGMsdAaY5V0w6VOLjrtBhAtpHTKMw55S2hiCRxOFAqPy7ge/hpHVsadIxJVT9MwXxz8luPHNqOGu2AtO+9G5+6IPUJxGkHXsC8wuycqPy7OYCdzgzjFY0Io4+8M3Gmf86LQVfpFFKpUxBF0EBQxifceqYHp4VMyQucSQqkQjcQUuRhhuHKS3OM7uPB+Xdhf6Qzzc1RyyFvj/k7xpQiTk3Gt91unGGtsLouH7sR41LgppzLw0iZTlmMYtppIs7XZTzfPAPsaq4BD1tnK0wxYtbB9EnXnOI8X6yfbU0MiIFalzHNRUzot9D+PWoygds1bZwVN3h2snFP1LoddpNdg35+PDyIIFifiM2wbY81jFbi54GhVwF2zkcbutBCfkZCPsG2Rb8G/Lz6N86tXkIuYucp5R/rF3R/X8+Hgr8WDduV49rruvLUy6xDdKge+/3Nx9ubu22/Fj86Km4KldEYCLOanZTIIDvWODpY94KKnzNIhIJo2dPrdejPWFg0hZdoOPLOldyrs9vOWboZLxg1+GzwfXzgo0k8lQR8Ze+Q1cEKpJmtHr6d/wc=) demonstrating a possible implementation.
I think that you should easily be able to transpose it to your specific case.

```
// This settings controls the handles size.
const HANDLES_RADIUS = 5;

// This flag allow us to know when we are dragging an handle.
let dragging = false;
// This will store the offset from the handle position to the
// mouse down point. This allow a better drag UX.
let offset;
// This will store the point representing the opposite rectangle corner from
// the one being dragged.
let oppositePoint;

// We start by creating a rectangle in the middle of the canvas.
// This rectangle will be replaced each time a corner is dragged.
let rectangle = createRectangle(view.center - 50, view.center + 50);

// Then, we create an handle for each of the corners.
// These will be used to modify the rectangle shape.
const handles = rectangle.segments.map((segment, index) => new Path.Rectangle({
    from: segment.point - HANDLES_RADIUS,
    to: segment.point + HANDLES_RADIUS,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    // We store the segment index bound to this specific handle in the custom
    // data object. This will allow us to know, when an handle is clicked,
    // which segment is concerned by the event.
    data: { segmentIndex: index },
    // On mouse down on an handle...
    onMouseDown: function(event) {
        // ...get and store the opposite segment point.
        // We will use it later to redraw the rectangle.
        const oppositeSegmentIndex = (this.data.segmentIndex + 2) % 4;
        oppositePoint = rectangle.segments[oppositeSegmentIndex].point;
        // Store the offset.
        offset = event.point - rectangle.segments[this.data.segmentIndex].point;
        // Activate dragging state.
        dragging = true;
    }
}));

// On mouse move...
function onMouseMove(event) {
    // ...don't do nothing if we are not dragging an handle.
    if (!dragging) {
        return;
    }
    // Get the new corner position by applying the offset to the event point.
    const activePoint = event.point + offset;
    // Recreate the rectangle with the new corner.
    rectangle.remove();
    rectangle = createRectangle(oppositePoint, activePoint);
    // For each corner...
    rectangle.segments.forEach((segment, index) => {
        // ...place an handle...
        handles[index].position = segment.point;
        // ...store the potentially new segment <=> corner bound.
        handles[index].data.segmentIndex = index;
    });
}

// On mouse up...
function onMouseUp() {
    // Disable dragging state
    dragging = false;
}


//
// HELPERS
//

// This method is used to avoid duplicating the rectangle instantiation code.
function createRectangle(from, to) {
    return new Path.Rectangle({
        from,
        to,
        strokeColor: 'orange'
    });
}
```

Comment: You are fantastic